# How to manipulate DOM element after its complete rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm using js and jquery for the manipulation of form elements

this form is for editing

it gets the data from the back end and then runs sequential functions to display the data:

1- click on the manual radio button (displays the new header field and the source header select box and the checkbox for type)

2- fill in the new header input field

3- Select the source header (this will bring the unique values of the source header and generate two inputs for each one (one for the old value and the second for the new value))

4- Select the type (manual (converts the new value from select to input) or MRSH (converts the new value from input to select))

5- fill the data that came from the server to inputs or select boxes.

the problem is in the last step (it doesn't work properly because the previous steps may take some time for rendering)

Here's the code:

```
    /**
     * Handle Edit Header in case of Manual
     * @param {Object} headerData
     * @param {string} columnName
     * @returns {void}
     */
    function handleEditManual(headerData, columnName) {
        $("#manual").click();

        // Set Column Name Field
        $("#column-name").val(columnName);

        // Set the Type according to the incoming type
        let values = headerData.values;

        addMappingPart(headerData).then(addInputsOrSelects(headerData)).then(function () {
            switch (mode) {
                case "manual":
                    fillInputFields(values);
                    break;

                case "MRSH":
                    fillSelectBoxes(values);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    // Step 2: Fill input fields
    function fillInputFields(values) {
        $(".source-inputs").each(function () {
            let sourceValue = $(this).data("value");
            let manualValue =
                values.find((value) => value.value === sourceValue).then ??
                null;
            $(this).next().find("input").val(manualValue);
        });
    }

    // Step 2: Fill input fields
    function fillSelectBoxes(values) {
        $(".source-inputs").each(function () {
            let sourceValue = $(this).data("value");
            let mrsvId =
                values.find((value) => value.value === sourceValue).id ?? null;
            $(this).next().find("select").val(mrsvId).trigger("change");
        });
    }

    function addMappingPart(headerData) {
        let sourceHeader = headerData.source_header;

        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            $("#source-header").val(sourceHeader).trigger("change");

            // Resolve the Promise to signal completion of Step 1
            resolve();
        });
    }

    function addInputsOrSelects(headerData) {
        let type = headerData.type ? true : false;
        let mrshId = headerData.mrsh_id ?? null;

        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            // Simulate some time to add input fields
            if (type) {
                $("#type-switch").click();
                mode = "MRSH";

                // Set the MRSH if the Type is MRSH
                $("#select-mrsh").val(mrshId).trigger("change");
            } else {
                mode = "manual";
            }

            // Resolve the Promise to signal completion of Step 1
            resolve();
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I tend to solve this with a global variable, something like `let FETCH_COUNT = 0`. Then right before your use `fetch`, increment the value and store the outcome into a local variable available to your fetch (`const MY_FETCH_INDEX = ++FETCH_COUNT;`. Then inside your resolution of the fetch, check if the `FETCH_COUNT === MY_FETCH_INDEX` and only then make the changes. If another fetch call happened in between, this will be false as its locally scoped.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your attempt:

- `.then(addInputsOrSelects(headerData))` doesn't pass a callback to `.then`, but instead immediately *executes* `addInputsOrSelects`. And the promise that it returns is of no use as argument for `.then()`.
- At the places where you create a new promise with `new Promise`, you immediately (synchronously) resolve them: this means that there will be no room for asynchronous UI-related updates. It is hardly ever useful to call `resolve` **synchronously** in the promise constructor callback.

A solution to have all rendering done before continuing with more code, is to rely on `requestAnimationFrame`. The callback passed to this function will be executed just before the next paint cycle occurs (which updates the screen), and if that callback also calls `requestAnimationFrame`, then the callback given there will only execute one paint cycle later. This function can be easily promisified so that you can chain a `then` to it or combine it with `await`.

I revamped your code a bit, adding after every call to `trigger` and `click` an `await` that allows a paint cycle to occur:

```
// Promisified requestAnimationFrame:
const justBeforePaint = () => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);

/**
 * Handle Edit Header in case of Manual
 * @param {Object} headerData
 * @param {string} columnName
 * @returns {void}
 */
async function handleEditManual(headerData, columnName) {
    await justBeforePaint(); // Await this immediately before doing anything else
    
    $("#manual").click();
    await justBeforePaint(); 

    // Set Column Name Field
    $("#column-name").val(columnName);

    // Set the Type according to the incoming type
    const values = headerData.values;
    addMappingPart(headerData);  
    await justBeforePaint();

    const mode = await addInputsOrSelects(headerData);
    switch (mode) {
    case "manual":
        fillInputFields(values);
        break;
    case "MRSH":
        fillSelectBoxes(values);
        break;
    }
    await justBeforePaint();
}

// Step 2: Fill input fields
function fillInputFields(values) {
    $(".source-inputs").each(function () {
        let sourceValue = $(this).data("value");
        let manualValue =
            values.find((value) => value.value === sourceValue).then ??
            null;
        $(this).next().find("input").val(manualValue);
    });
}

// Step 2: Fill input fields
function fillSelectBoxes(values) {
    $(".source-inputs").each(function () {
        const sourceValue = $(this).data("value");
        const mrsvId =
            values.find((value) => value.value === sourceValue).id ?? null;
        $(this).next().find("select").val(mrsvId).trigger("change");
    });
}

function addMappingPart(headerData) {
    const sourceHeader = headerData.source_header;
    $("#source-header").val(sourceHeader).trigger("change");
}

async function addInputsOrSelects(headerData) {
    const mrshId = headerData.mrsh_id ?? null;
    if (headerData.type) {
        $("#type-switch").click();
        await justBeforePaint();
        // Set the MRSH if the Type is MRSH
        $("#select-mrsh").val(mrshId).trigger("change");
        await justBeforePaint();
        return "MRSH";
    } else {
        return "manual";
    }
}
```

Some of the `justBeforePaint` calls might not be necessary -- it depends on what exactly those `trigger()` and `click()` calls do asynchronously, and whether the rest of the code depends on that.